# Applying margin to single <li>

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to move the margin on the 3rd `<li>`, without affecting the prior two.

I guess I have to create a seperate li class, with margin "x" and then apply??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="no">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="../style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu-bg">
        <div id="menu-text">
            <ul id="list">
                <li>
                 <a href="/solmai/index.php"><font class="cur">VERBIER</a></font><br>
                 <a href="../whistler/index.html">WHISTLER</a><br>
                </li>

                <li><a href="/solmai/verbier/chalet.php"><font class="cur">CHALET</font></a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">AESTHETIC CLINIQUE</a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">SPORTS CLINIQUE</a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">MEMBERS LOUNGE</a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">GYM</a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">GALLERY</a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">VERBIER NEWS</a>
                </li> 

                 <li><a href="/solmai/verbier/chalet.php">THE EXPERIENCE</a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">SERVICES</a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">ADVENTURE</a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">TOUR</a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">GALLERY</a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">REVIEWS</a><br>
                    <a href="../verbier/verbier/home.php">LOCATION</a>
                </li>

         </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your proposed solution sounds like it should work. Did you try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#list li:last-child{
  margin: ...
}
```

Or if you have more following, you can use `:nth-child(3)`

Also note that the [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/font) tag is deprecated in HTML5 (the doctype you appear to be using)

Comment: OK thanks so much.

Can you please show me how to declare in the HTML. Sorry, new to this!

Comment: You declare it in the CSS file, just like any other styles you have in it

Comment: Actually, is it possible to apply the margin to just that specific li, rather than every time it's the last child? in different areas I dont want that applied to the last child element

Comment: Yes, `#list li:nth-child(3){ ... }` will apply the style to the 3rd list item only

Comment: ahh perfect. Thanks so much. Where do I send the chocolates??

Comment: IE8 doesn't support `nth-child(x)`

Comment: meh.. I don't like candy :)